# VSCode PHP Debug hovering over properties

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

Using PHP Debug (Xdebug) I can hover over objects and arrays just fine to see values but this only seems to work on the 'parent' object, I was wondering if there is a way to hover over array elements or object properties to quickly see their individual values?

E.g. instead of hovering over `$MyObject`, I want to hover over `SomeValue` to see the individual value. I could do this in another IDE, it's much quicker when working with large objects/arrays.

```
$MyObject->SomeValue
$MyObject['SomeValue']
```